# How can i report the progress to label or a backgroundworker from static class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public class DirectoryIterator
        {
            public static int Iterate(string root)
            {
                var iterator = new DirectoryIterator();
                iterator.iterate(root);
                return iterator.count;
            }

            private void iterate(string root)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (string directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root))
                        iterate(directory);

                    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, "*.txt"))
                    {
                        // load(file);

                        ++count;

                        // Now count is the actual number of files processed,
                        // so you can use it for updateProgress()
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }

            private int count;

            private DirectoryIterator() { }
        }
```

And using it:

```
int count = DirectoryIterator.Iterate("C:\\temp\\");
```

Then i can report the count but that's in the end of the process.
I want to report the progress twice. First time when it's getting the directories:

```
foreach (string directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root))
                        iterate(directory);
```

To report here to the progresschanged event the directory name and also to count the number of directories and report the counting in real time.

Second:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(root, "*.txt"))
                    {
                        // load(file);

                        ++count;

                        // Now count is the actual number of files processed,
                        // so you can use it for updateProgress()
                    }
```

To report here the files names and the number of files in real time.

The problem is since it's static i can't call any control from inside the class not the backgroundworker and not labels.

Answer (score 2):

Add a parameter for a callback to your static `Iterate` method. Invoke the callback as appropriate within the instance `iterate` method to notify the caller of progress updates.

You'll need a private constructor on the `DirectoryIterator` class that accepts the callback, too. E.g.:

```
public static int Iterate(string root, Action<int> callback)
{
    var iterator = new DirectoryIterator(callback);
    iterator.iterate(root);
    return iterator.count;
}
```

The callback could be as simple as an `Action<int>` if all you need to do is report the current iteration count.